# Can the same subset be both open and closed?

Tags: general-topology

This is a follow up response to: [Counterexample to " a closed ball in M is a closed subset."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399410/counterexample-to-a-closed-ball-in-m-is-a-closed-subset)

I'm trying to understand this using **only** the given definitions of: Metric space, open/closed ball, open/closed subset.

Let Metric $$M= \mathbb{Z} \cap [1,10]; d(x,y) = |x-y| $$
Let $P$ be the open ball: $P=B_{2.1}(5)=\{y \in M: d(5,y)<2.1 \},$ 
Let $C$ be the closed ball: $C=\overline B_{2.1}(5)=\{y \in M: d(5,y)\leq 2.1 \},$

Thus, $P=C=\{3,4,5,6,7\}$.
Does this mean $\{3,4,5,6,7\}$ is simultaneously open and closed (in $M$)?

Comment: A set that is both open and closed is sometimes referred to as "clopen".

Comment: Another, maybe more striking example of this phenomenon: there's a natural metric on the set of infinite binary sequences, $d(f, g)=2^{-n}$ where $n$ is the first bit on which $f$ and $g$ differ (with $d(f, g)=0$ if $f=g$). Here, there is a family of "basic open balls" so that every open set is a union of such balls, but **each** of these basic open balls is also closed! So there can be lots of clopen-ness, even in natural examples, without the metric structure being trivial.

Comment: If the space is __not connected__ then it has subsets that are both open and closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, $\{3,4,5,6,7\}$ is simultaneously open and closed in $M$. In fact, every singleton is open and closed, for the same reason: for example, $\{x\}$ is equal to both the open and closed balls of radius $1/2$ centered at $x$. This means that every subset of $M$ is open and closed, since every subset is a finite union of singletons, and finite unions preserve both openness and closedness.

Comment: To connect this with the other answer, this means precisely that $M$ is a *discrete space*, which is by definition a space in which every subset is open (and therefore, also closed, since its complement is open).